# How to prevent entities from being listed as services in the container?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, symfony4, ioc-container

When I run the command below, I can see that Symfony considers every class in the app as a potential injectable service:

```
$ bin/console debug:container

Symfony Container Services
==========================

 ------------------------------- -----------------------------
  Service ID                     Class name                                                                                 
 ------------------------------- -----------------------------

  App\Domain\Model\Product       App\Domain\Model\Product                                                                   
  App\Domain\Model\Site          App\Domain\Model\Site                                                                      
  App\Domain\Model\User          App\Domain\Model\User                                                                      
  ...
```

This includes entities and value objects, that obviously should not, and will not, ever be injected, and as such should not be registered in the container.

**Is this expected?** Is there a way to either:

- explicitly blacklist classes from being registered in the container,
- or explicitly whitelist services that should be registered in the container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is expected.

have a look at config/services.yaml where the magic happens (at least this happens in my services.yaml):

```
# removed lines for readability before, after and in-between the following
services:
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests}'
```

this essentially should turn everything except for entities, migrations and tests in the `src` directory into services. you can adapt this to your needs obviously.

So essentially ... if you remove that `App\` entry, you would be bound to explicitly <strike>add</strike> whitelist all classes that are supposed to be services.

Blacklisting on the other hand is shown in the example, although the example is quite general. Maybe there are more sophisticated ways to do this ...

Comment: Thank you! I guess whitelisting happens with `include:`?

Comment: "whitelisting" happens by the `resource:`